# Whenever there is a commit in master branch, then commit should be automatically cherry-picked to another branch in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

Is there any way to by which if there is a commit in master branch, then commit should automatically cherry-picked to another branch in the same project in gitlab.

Comment: "Automatically cherry-pick" sounds odd, since cherry-pick is one of these operations which *can* result in conflict, thus creating the need for human resolution. How would you ideally want these cases to be handled?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, where cherry-picking commits from master to another branch, wholesale, is the solution?

Comment: I would be very surprised if gitlab has a feature to do this (with the caveat that @RomainValeri mentioned with conflicts) as it's a very strange thing to do. As such, I'm pretty sure you're going to have to build the pipeline for this yourself.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.